# Using set -e / set +e in bash with functions

Tags: bash, shell

I've been using a simple bash preamble like this in my scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
```

In conjunction with modularity / using functions this has bitten me today.

So, say I have a function somewhere like

```
foo() {
  #edit: some error happens that make me want to exit the function and signal that to the caller 
  return 2
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to use multiple small files, include their functions in other files and then call these functions like

```
set +e
foo
rc=$?
set -e
```

. This works for exactly two layers of routines. But if foo is also calling subroutines like that, the last setting before the return will be `set -e`, which will make the script exit on the return - I cannot override this in the calling function. So, what I had to do is

```
foo() {
  #calling bar() in a shielded way like above
  #..      

  set +e
  return 2
}
```

Which I find very counterintuitive (and also not what I want - what if in some contexts I'd like to use the function without shielding against failures, while in other contexts I want to handle the cleanup?) What's the best way to handle this? Btw. I'm doing this on OSX, I haven't tested whether this behaviour is different on Linux.

Comment: wait, could you expand? Do I add this in the caller? What does the colon do?

Comment: Could you expand on how I'm abusing return? How am I meant to signal error from within a function then? (sorry if I wasn't clear enough - the `return 2` is only done in an error condition.

Comment: You're not, but I thought you were. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Shell functions don't really have "return values", just exit codes.

You could add `&& :` to the caller, this makes the command "tested", and won't exit it:

```
foo() {
    echo 'x'
    return 42
}

out=$(foo && :)
echo $out
```

The `:` is the "null command" (ie. it doesn't do anything). In this case it doesn't even get executed, since it only gets run if `foo` return 0 (which it doesn't).

This outputs:

```
x
```

It's arguably a bit ugly, but then again, all of shell scripting is arguably a bit ugly ;-)

Quoting `sh(1)` from FreeBSD, which explains this better than bash's man page:

```
 -e errexit
         Exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive
         mode.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly
         tested if the command is part of the list used to control an if,
         elif, while, or until; if the command is the left hand operand of
         an “&&” or “||” operator; or if the command is a pipeline preceded
         by the ! operator.  If a shell function is executed and its exit
         status is explicitly tested, all commands of the function are con‐
         sidered to be tested as well.
```

Comment: (damn, no newlines in comments ;) ). Thanks man. I see now. So from now on, if I want to execute a function a 'tested' manner, I'll do

     set +e
     foo && : 
     rc=$?
     set -e

Comment: @MichelMüller You don't need to do anything with `set`; you just use `set -e` once to enable this in your script, and then to "circumvent it", as it were, use `&& :`.

Comment: This is quite a late follow-up, please excuse me. I was just thinking, when I'm doing

    foo && : \n
    rc=$?

in order to handle error conditions in the caller, wouldn't it be cleaner to write `foo && rc=$?`. Would that still be within best practices?

Comment: @MichelMüller I think *most* people would feel that one statement per line is *usually* the best course of action; but opinions differ. It depends on who you're programming this for (yourself? customer? internal use in an organisation?), expected code standards, etc...

Comment: Shouldn't this syntax be `out=$(foo || :)`, i.e., if foo's exit status is non-zero (FALSE), that status is ORd with the null statement's ':' exit status which is TRUE, and therefore `FALSE || TRUE == TRUE`, and consequently the following statement `echo $out` is evaluated.