# bash: is there a flag to make a function to return in case of error?

Tags: bash, sh

I am using "set -e" to make the script exit in case of an error, but I don't want it to exit if I have an error inside a function, I would like the function to return error instead

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func() {
    echo 1
    # code ...
    cause_error
    echo This should not print
}
func
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo I want this print
else
    echo This should not print either
fi
```

The output of this script is:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh
1
```

But I would like it to be:

```
1
I want this print
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to test the exit status of every command executed inside the function?

Comment: In general, don't use `set -e`; do your own error handling. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
set -e

function foo() {
    echo Foo
    cause_error
}

echo Before
set +o errexit; foo; set -o errexit;
echo Will get here
foo
echo Wont get here
```

Comment: why you set +o errexit...why not set +e

Comment: is there no set +e?

Comment: Yeah there is +e too. Its the same.

Comment: Thanks, The problem with this solution is that the function doesn't return on an error, if you add an `echo bar` just after the `cause_error`, it will get executed in the `set +o errexit; foo; set -o errexit;` :(

Answer (score 0):

The behavior which you are asking is not possible. You want the function to return on error and the script to not exit, even with the `set -e` option. The requirement you are asking for the bash interpreter is to check exit status for each line and if it is inside a function return non-zero code else exit.

You cannot do the exact requirement which you are asking for. But you can choose to disable the `set -e` for the execution of the function. The way to disable `set -e` is to use `set +e` option or use `&& :` trick

Here is example updated code using `&& :` trick

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func() {
    echo 1
    # code ...
    return 1
    echo This should not print
}
func && :
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo I want this print
else
    echo This should not print either
fi
```

Output:

```
1
I want this print
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27793459/2032943

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add a `out=$(func && :); echo "$out"` in the function call, but the problem is that it executes the `echo This should not print`, the function doesn't return just after the error

Comment: The return from the function becomes its exit status in bash

Comment: I updated the question with s/false/cause_error to show that is a faulty command. Your answer works if I explicitly add a `return 1` there, but it doesn't in case an error occurs inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly comparing `$?` is an antipattern, but in addition, getting rid of it will also bypass `set -e` because it does not fail when the failure happens in a condition.

The proper syntax for what you are trying to do, regardless of `set -e`, is

```
if func; then
    echo I want this print
else
    echo This should not print either
fi
```

The failure inside the function *will* cause the function to report an error, like you are saying in the prose description of your requirements, but that also means that the conditional will print `This should not print either`.  If you don't want that, maybe edit your question to clarify this paradoxical requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't print `This should not print either` (which is correct), but it prints `This should not print`. As stated in the question, I want the function to return when an error occurs, so it shouldn't execute the line `echo This should not print`

Comment: My bad, you're right.  I'm tempted to delete this answer but I'll leave it here for the time being.  If I can find an earlier question which addresses your concern, I'll probably mark this as a duplicate.