# why ‘&&’ disables errexit(set -e)?

Tags: bash

consider script here:

```bash
set -e
make && make install
echo "SHOULD NOT BE HERE"
```

I expect that if `make` fails, the script will be aborted, but it's not:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
SHOULD NOT BE HERE
```

But, if I changed it like this:

```bash
set -e
make 
make install
echo "SHOULD NOT BE HERE"
```

It works as expected:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Why this happens?
Due to `make && make install` is commonly used in my build script, how should I use it correctly?

And please DO NOT link this question to [Using set -e / set +e in bash with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793264/using-set-e-set-e-in-bash-with-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1), it's not the same question.

Comment: `make && make install` is a list command where the second part is only executed if the first part is successful. So it acts like a single command and returns an exit status. If you want exit-on-errror, then use `make && make install || exit 1`

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but your answer is in the question you linked. Using `&&` makes the left hand side a tested command, even if the right hand side never runs. Try something like `false && false` in a `set -e` environment and see what happens. (`false` always returns a bad exit code)

Comment: @Wiimm that is not quite right, nor does it matter here (but your solution works). If it was a single command then it would still quit. run `false && false` and then `echo $?`. You will see a `1` not a `0`

Comment: If `make` would succeed and `make install` would fail, your script would be aborted by `-e`. This is how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [the answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27793459/10805404):

> Quoting `sh(1)` from FreeBSD, which explains this better than bash's man page:

```
 -e errexit
         Exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive
         mode.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly
         tested if the command is part of the list used to control an if,
         elif, while, or until; if the command is the left hand operand of
         an “&&” or “||” operator; or if the command is a pipeline preceded
         by the ! operator.  If a shell function is executed and its exit
         status is explicitly tested, all commands of the function are con‐
         sidered to be tested as well.
```

`errexit` exits only if an **untested command fails**. Using `&&` (or `||`) will means that bash considers the command to the left of `&&` to be explicitly tested (which in turn means that it will not be handled by `errexit`).

See also [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) (specifically the part about *list constructs*).

As far a I know, there is no way to achieve what you would like by setting bash options.